# No axis named URL for object type DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I think my code is almost complete but I keep getting this error "No axis named URL for object type Dataframe"  There's a column named URL and I know it works since the table output includes a URL column. Here's two samples of my code

```
rows_processed=[]
    for item in items.findAll("div", {"class": "item-cell"}):
        itemTitle = item.find("a", {"class": "item-title"})
        itemPromo = item.find("p", {"class": "item-promo"})
        itemPrice = item.find("li", {"class": "price-current"})
   
    row = []
    row.append(itemTitle.text)
    row.append(itempromo.text)
    row.append(itemPrice.text)
    row.append(itemTitle.get("href"))
    
    rows_processed.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows_processed, columns=["Item Title ", "Status", "Price", "URL"])
```

```
while (True):
    try:
        url = "https://url.ca" 
        items = check_for_stock(url)
        in_stock = df.loc[df['Price'] <= 270.00][df['Status'] == "Available"]
        if not in_stock.empty:
            item_to_purchase = in_stock.loc(0)
            buyItem(item_to_purchase("URL"))
            break
```

The error with the code happens with

buyItem(item_push("URL"))
or

driver.get(item_push("URL"))

But the table after the first sample of code works and displays all URLs I'm looking for. My goal is to narrow it down to one url with criteria and then select the URL from the dataframe.

Comment: Maybe you could show an example of your dataframe with the code you wrote. For more info look at the [mcve]

Comment: @zipa I added samples of my code that I thought were relevant

Answer (score 0):

You just need to look up the "URL" value differently, see below:

```
rows_processed = [
    ['shoes', 'Available', 270.00, 'www.abc.com'],
    ['jacket', 'Available', 260.00, 'www.bbb.com']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows_processed, columns=["Item Title ", "Status", "Price", "URL"])

in_stock = df.loc[df['Price'] <= 270.00][df['Status'] == "Available"]
if not in_stock.empty:
    url_you_want = in_stock["URL"][0]  # 0th item.  You could loop through them all
    buyItem(url_you_want)
    # item_to_purchase = in_stock.loc(0)
    # buyItem(item_to_purchase("URL"))
    # break     # no need to break, you are not in a loop
```